# tcp connection with machine via ethernet using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp

I want to make a simple formapp using vb.net to send ASCII strings to a machine, that responds after every command. i.e., if i send "AA" it responds "123".

I can already open the connection cause if i check the connection with hyperterminal it says that the port is already being used. Yet, when i send commands i have no answer back.

I kinda adapted the template codes for server/client chat with tcp:

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading 

Dim Listener As New TcpListener(65535)
Dim Client As New TcpClient
Dim Message As String = "

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
If Listener.Pending = True Then
    Message = ""
Client = Listener.AcceptTcpClient()

Dim Reader As New StreamReader(Client.GetStream())
While Reader.Peek > -1
    Message = Message + Convert.ToChar(Reader.Read()).ToString
End While
RichTextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black
RichTextBox1.Text += Message + vbCrLf
End Sub

Private Sub btnSend_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
If txtName.Text = "" Or cmbAddress.Text = "" Then
    MessageBox.Show("All Fields must be Filled", _
                    "Error", _
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
Else
    Try
        Client = New TcpClient(cmbAddress.Text, 65535)

        Dim Writer As New StreamWriter(Client.GetStream())
        Writer.Write(txtName.Text & " Says:  " & txtmessage.Text)
        Writer.Flush()

        RichTextBox1.Text += (txtName.Text & " Says:  " & txtmessage.Text) + vbCrLf
        txtmessage.Text = ""
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex)
        Dim Errorresult As String = ex.Message
        MessageBox.Show(Errorresult & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                        "Please Review Client Address", _
                        "Error Sending Message", _
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

End If
End Sub
```

is there a muuuuuuuch better way to do this? i read about .net.sockets but i coulndt get out of this.

and the manuals say nothing about how the machine operates. if it's a client, server, host.. can someone help me here? thank you !

Comment: There is a complete solution using synchronous and asynchronous sockets on MSDN. Just copy and paste that code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Once i'm using a simple request/response protocol ( do not require receiving and sending concurrently and can be handled in a single thread) which one should i use? i guess both will work anyway ( if i manage to make them work in a windowsform)

Comment: you could use my open source library. http://griffinframework.net/doc/networking/

Comment: @jgauffin idk how but i got there before! the thing is i don't know how to implement this. do i have to build a server anyway? cause i want to make the connection between machine and PC, and the machine accepts any connection in that port. it's like i don't need it ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text.UTF7Encoding
Public Class Form1
Dim open As TcpListener
Dim server As TcpListener
Dim client, host As TcpClient
Dim dati, hdat As NetworkStream
Dim ip As String = Nothing
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ip = TextBox1.Text
    client = New TcpClient
    client.Connect(ip, 2101)
    If client.Connected = True Then
        dati = client.GetStream
        MsgBox("Connected", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Button1.Enabled = False
        Timer1.Start()
    Else
        MsgBox("Error", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If client.Available > 0 Then
        Dim t(client.Available - 1) As Byte
        dati.Read(t, 0, t.Length)
        Dim testo As String = UTF7.GetString(t)
        RichTextBox1.Text += vbCrLf & "server : " & testo & vbCrLf
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim t() As Byte = UTF7.GetBytes(TextBox2.Text & vbCrLf)
    dati.Write(t, 0, t.Length)
    RichTextBox1.Text += vbCrLf & TextBox2.Text & vbCrLf
End Sub
End Class
```